# How do I know if jQuery node would be visible before attaching to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing

If an element is attached to the DOM, we can query if it is visible in jQuery with:

```
> $('#element-id').is(':visible')
true
> $('#element-id').toggle(false).is(':visible')
false
> $('#element-id').toggle(true).is(':visible')
true
```

But what if my element is not yet attached to the DOM? How do I check if it would be visible when attached without actually attaching it?

An unattached element always returns `false` to `.is(':visible')` because it is, obviously, not really visible yet:

```
> $('<div>').is(':visible')
false
> $('<div>').toggle(true).is(':visible')
false
```

I know the element is reacting to the toggle because of its style:

```
> $('<div>').attr('style')
undefined
> $('<div>').toggle(true).attr('style')
'display: block;'
> $('<div>').toggle(false).attr('style')
'display: none;'
```

But manually checking the style attribute is fragile, as different elements would have different styles attached depending if they're visible or not and I'd have to do a string containment check:

```
> $('<span>', {style: 'font-style:italic'}).toggle(true).attr('style')
'font-style: italic; display: inline;'
```

And the reason I'm checking if unattached elements would be visible if attached to the DOM, instead of simply attaching them, is because I'm running automated unit tests with components that call `.toggle(is_visible)` on jQuery elements that are not connected to the DOM during the test.

These components come from a framework that, for pratical purposes, I cannot change, but which I want to know if they are passing the right `is_visible` for the situation under test.